# InternalError: Failed copying input tensor from

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow2.0

When I use tensorflow to build a 1D-CNN model, i got this problem.

My GPU is RTX3070Ti and tensorflow version is 2.10.1 and the python environment is 3.9.2 64-bit.

The same code was used in different model successfully, only "model=Sequential()" is different.

I have been trapped for about one week.

I almost tested all the methods on the internet.

batch_size=50,num_classes=12,epochs=5 for testing.

Under is the error msssage.

```
InternalError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
d:\python\tyty.ipynb Cell 12 line 3
      1 print(model.metrics_names)
      2 model.fit(trX,trY,batch_size=batch_size,epochs=epochs,validation_data=(teX,teY),verbose=1)
----> 3 test_label = np.argmax(model.predict(test_data), axis=-1)
      4 print(test_label)

File c:\Users\Jie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-    packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py:70, in filter_traceback.<locals>.error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
     67     filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
     68     # To get the full stack trace, call:
     69     # `tf.debugging.disable_traceback_filtering()`
---> 70     raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
     71 finally:
     72     del filtered_tb

File c:\Users\Jie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-  packages\tensorflow\python\framework\constant_op.py:102, in convert_to_eager_tensor(value, ctx, dtype)
    100     dtype = dtypes.as_dtype(dtype).as_datatype_enum
    101 ctx.ensure_initialized()
--> 102 return ops.EagerTensor(value, ctx.device_name, dtype)

InternalError: Failed copying input tensor from /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0 to   /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 in order to run _EagerConst: Dst tensor is not initialized`
```

I have checked.

tensorflow version with cuDnn and CUDA.

GPU memory is enough(I only have one GPU and only implement the code).

Only use CPU without GPU was successful.

the data has 12 channels, and 300000 data each channel.

The CNN model have 9 convolutional layers and 3 maxpooling layers, I tested only 3 convolutional layers and 1 maxpooling layer still appeared the same error.